# How to count number of images in view.phtml page?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, product-view

I want to add HTML class in view.phtml as per product images.

Like: If product have one image then class add `img_1`. if have two then `img_2`

How to get number of images count in view.phtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<?php 
    $GalleryImages = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())
                    ->getMediaGalleryImages();

    $count_img = 1;

     if(count($GalleryImages)) {
       foreach($GalleryImages as $simplemediagalleryimage) {
        $count_img++;
         }
     }
echo "img_".$count_img;
 ?>
```

Comment: The gallery images are usually output by view/media.phtml, not view.phtml, and the rwd media.phtml template already assigns each image an id of the format image-$i

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
    $galleryImages = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages();

    $totalProductImgs = count($galleryImages);

    $class = "img_"$totalProductImgs;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $GalleryImages = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())
                  ->getMediaGalleryImages();

 echo  $totalImages = count($GalleryImages);
```